# Next.js CredentialsProvider returning null after trying to add new params

Tags: next.js13, credentials, next-auth, react-typescript, app-router

I'm trying to add refresh_token and expires_at to my current CredentialsProvider in next-auth.

Everything works perfectly on local, but on the deployed app (using DeployHQ)credentials response is null and the app breaks:
[image: Empty credentials response]

Payload for credentials looks ok, and all the variables are passed correctly, any idea what might be the cause of this?

**NEXTAUTH_URL**, **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** and all the env variables have been set correctly.
Again, this only happens on the deployed version of the app, locally everything works well.

Relevant code:

**next-auth.ts**:

```
import { refreshTokens, signOutUser, verifyMfaCode } from '@/api/auth';
import { AuthOptions, Session, User } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { setAxiosDefaults } from './axios';

async function refreshAccessToken(token: JWT): Promise<JWT> {
    try {
        const refreshedTokens = await refreshTokens(
            token.refresh_token?.toString() ?? '',
            'access',
        );

        return {
            ...token,
            token: refreshedTokens.tokens.access_token,
            token_expires_at: refreshedTokens.tokens.expires_at,
            refresh_token: refreshedTokens.tokens.refresh_token,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            ...token,
            error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
        };
    }
}

export const jwt = async ({ token, user }: { token: JWT; user: User }) => {
    if (user) {
        token.refresh_token = user.refresh_token;
        token.token_expires_at = user.expires_at;
        token.token = user.accessToken;
        token.user = {
            id: user.id,
            accountId: user.accountId,
            mfaToken: user.mfaToken,
            status: user.status,
        };

        return token;
    }

    const currentTimeInSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    if (currentTimeInSeconds < Number(token.token_expires_at)) {
        return token;
    }

    return refreshAccessToken(token);
};

export const session = async ({
    session,
    token,
}: {
    session: Session;
    token: JWT;
}): Promise<Session> => {
    if (token.user) {
        session.refreshToken = token.refresh_token;
        session.expiresIn = token.token_expires_at;
        session.token = token.token;
        session.user = token.user;

        setAxiosDefaults({
            token: token.token,
            mfaToken: token.user.mfaToken,
        });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(session);
};

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            type: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                refresh_token: { label: 'RefreshToken', type: 'text' }, // If I comment this, everything works perfectly
                expires_at: { label: 'TokenExpires', type: 'text' }, // If I comment this, everything works perfectly
                code: { label: 'Code', type: 'text' },
                token: { label: 'Token', type: 'text' },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                if (typeof credentials !== 'undefined') {
                    if (!credentials?.token) {
                        throw new Error('Internal server error');
                    }

                    const { data: response, status } = await verifyMfaCode({
                        code: credentials.code,
                        token: credentials.token,
                    });

                    if (status === 401) {
                        throw new Error('Invalid code');
                    }

                    if (status === 500) {
                        throw new Error('Internal server error');
                    }

                    return {
                        id: response.user.id,
                        accessToken: credentials.token,
                        expires_at: credentials.expires_at, // If I comment this, everything works perfectly
                        refresh_token: credentials.refresh_token, // If I comment this, everything works perfectly
                        mfaToken: response.mfa_token,
                        accountId: response.user?.account?.id || null,
                        status: response.user?.status || null,
                    } as User;
                }

                return null;
            },
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: '/signin',
        signOut: '/signout',
    },
    jwt: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    callbacks: {
        jwt,
        session,
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }: { url: string; baseUrl: string }) {
            return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
        },
    },
    events: {
        signOut: async ({ token }) => {
            if (token.user?.mfaToken && token.token) {
                await signOutUser();
            }
        },
    },
};
```

Form.tsx where I call next-auth/react's **signIn** method is getting called:

```
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TForm> = async ({ code }) => {
        setFormError('');

        await signIn('credentials', {
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            expires_at: expiresAt,
            code: code,
            token: accessToken,
            redirect: false,
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response?.error) {
                setFormError('Incorrect code');
            } else {
                localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
                localStorage.removeItem('expiresAt');
                localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
                router.push('/signin/onboarding');
            }
        });
    };
```

Environment:

```
System:
OS: macOS 14.1.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 48.13 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 9.6.7 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm
pnpm: 8.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/pnpm
Browsers:
Chrome: 120.0.6099.199
Edge: 120.0.2210.91
Safari: 17.1
npmPackages:
next: 13.4.11 => 13.4.11
next-auth: ^4.22.3 => 4.22.4
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
```